# Cannot modify files in /media

Tags: permissions

I am not able modify files in `/media`. I cannot delete nor create new folder.
I have disabled Fast bootup and hiberfile.sys, but I set the permissions to root.
How to give the owner the permissions?

Comment: In terminal, you can log in as root by doing: `sudo -s`.

Comment: Doing this would give me access but I am not able to download anything in this partition as I get the permission denied error, i.e , qbittorrent gives me the I/O error - Permission Denied.

Comment: That's how it should be. The directory `/media` has a special purpose in the system, and that purpose *does not* include it being used as a dumping ground by regular users. (The system uses `/media` to create ephemeral mount points on the fly for removable media.) Generally a regular user is lord and master of their own `$HOME` but has limited rights elsewhere, unless arranged otherwise. You should *never* repurpose system directories, but rather make your own directories for your own purposes.

Comment: /media has the two main partitions of my HDD which I use mostly. Not having the access to delete or modify any files in it can be a hindrance. Is there no workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Set up those partitions so they are mounted to you in the fstab file all the time. You can do this by creating an entry in fstab for that filesystem.

You have to know either the path (e.g. /dev/sda3, the UUID (e.g. UUID=1C77E534564D900) or a name you assign to it (with e2label)

You then add an entry into the /etc/fstab for the partition assigning ownership to you).

Here is an example of a partition (in this case an ntfs partition) that I set up:

Using UUID:

```
UUID=1C77E51312345900 /home/joe/Libraries   ntfs-3g fs-name=Library,x-gvfs-symbolic-icon=Library   ,permissions,nosuid,nodev,noexec,uid=1001,gid=1001,rw,umask=22,dmask=27,fmask=137    0   0
```

Using Previously assigned name:

```
LABEL=Library  /home/joe/Libraries  ntfs-3g fs-name=Library,x-gvfs-symbolic-icon=Library,permissions,nosuid,nodev,uid=1001,gid=1001,rw,dmask=27,fmask=137   0   0
```

/swapfile   none    swap    sw  0   0

Note, you use one or the other.

Note: The uid and gid are the numbers for my user name in  the /etc/passwd and /etc/group files

Note: /home/joe/Libraries is a directory you create. Use any name you want but it has to match the path in the fstab entry.

Comment: For this, is it mandatory to install ntfs-3g or i can simply use ntfs?

Comment: @HardikSomani you can write `ntfs` there instead in `/etc/fstab` (they mean the same thing), but you do need to install the `ntfs-3g` package with `sudo apt install ntfs-3g` if it's not already installed for either `ntfs` or `ntfs-3g` to work in `/etc/fstab`.